# How do I route traffic between eth0:0 and eth0

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I have been trying to convert my linux box which is running Mint into a router. `eth0` has a public IP address of `71.xx.xx.xx`. I created an eth0:0 and gave it an IP address of `10.0.0.100`. I started a DHCP server that is on eth0 (because it won't use `eth0:0`) and that's giving out addresses between `10.0.0.101` and `10.0.0.200`. I can ping between `eth0` and `eth0:0` on the same machine. I have a another laptop connected to the linux box via a switch and it's able to receive an IP address via the DHCP server.

The problem is with routing traffic from `eth0:0` and `eth0` (and vice-versa) so that computers on the private, `10.0.0.x` network can access the internet via the static IP on `eth0`.